# Smarty caching problems with nested templates

Tags: php, templates, caching, include, smarty

I have a problem in caching in nested templates in Smarty 3. It seems that when I do an `{include}` Smarty ignores the caching settings of the caller template. For example, supposing smarty cache has been enabled in the controller:

In template1.tpl:

```
{include file='template2.tpl' nocache}
```

In template2.tpl:

```
{include file='template3.tpl'}
```

In template3.tpl

```
{$smarty.now}
```

The `{$smarty.now}` value displayed on page is, until the cache is not cleared, always equal to the time of the first page visualization, although the first subtemplate is forced to be not cached.
This is an annoying problem for me, since I need to control caching settings of *all* the content of template2.tpl and its subtemplates from template1.tpl.

Are there elegant workarounds?

Comment: If my answer helped you, you should consider marking it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Smarty does not cache content of template2 (move `{$smarty.now}` their), but it does cache template3. Include it with nocache too.

I experienced the same problem and I redesign my template, so I'm able to cache most of it and only the parts without need of caching I surrounded with `{nocache} content {/nocache}`